# "Could not find source connection" in Network Manager

Tags: networking, network-manager, pptp

If the contents of

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

There is no error for a PPTP-connection declared in Network Manager. It works when I right click on it and connect.

However if the contents are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The error `Could not find source connection` pops-up. How can it depend on it?

Answer (score 0):

See `man Networkmanager.conf` about the ifupdown `managed` property. If you specify a device in /etc/network/interfaces, by default the device becomes unmanaged. As you'd see in `nmcli device` output.

If you use NetworkManager, I would not also configure the device in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Or, if you want to also use NetworkManager on that device, tell it to manage the device despite it's in interfaces file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. That's what helped me.

In

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

I set:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

The contents of

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Rebooted the PC. Just restarting the **network-manager** or/and **networking** service didn't have any effect, so I took a standard Windows-approach.

If `/etc/network/interfaces`

only contains:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I would have the problem I reported about earlier [Red icon for wired ethernet in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223687/red-icon-for-wired-ethernet-in-ubuntu)